# Does Sonar Jira plugin supports REST communication with Jira 6.0 as SOAP is deprecated

Tags: sonarqube

As Jira 6.0 deprecates SOAP (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/SOAP+and+XML-RPC+API+Deprecated+in+JIRA+6.0) does Sonar Jira plugin support REST communication with Jira 6.0 server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does but it's still working on the deprecated API.

Comment: I am trying to set this up as we speak.  If it supports REST, how do I make it work?  Can you expand on your answer?